# Database: Splitting tables based on logically grouped optional columns

Tags: database-design, relational-theory, rdbms

I keep having this argument with my management about splitting the tables. I prefer splitting a database table to multiple tables based on attributes that can be grouped together. The columns which are always not filled in and are almost always `Null` (optional).

Here is an example:

`appointment`

```
- id (PK)
- time
- category
- status
- employee_id
- visitor_id
- optional_registration_time
- optional_registration_message
- optional_registration_feedback
- optional_registration_image
```

All the columns named `optional_registration_*` are optional fields. They might or might not be filled in for every row.

And since they are optional and can be logically be grouped together, my approach was to split them off to a different table. Like this

`appointment_registration`:

```
- appointment_id (FK)
- time
- message
- feedback
- image
```

Although this is just an example, but it pretty much explains my dilemma. I prefer splitting it off, but my management insists because they belong together, they should be in one table. I don't agree that just because they belong together, doesn't mean they can't be associated with a different table.

By splitting them off, the new table `appointment_registration` will only have entries that are appropriate. And the table looks lean.

Which is the better approach?

Answer (score 0):

In the strictest sense, they should be in their own table(s) because it avoids the issue of the nullability of the columns.  It's not that any one of those columns can be NULL independently - they are *optional*, not NULLable.

Technically one *could* write a check constraint to ensure that rule is enforced, but there are other good reasons for keeping optional columns separate:

1. There is clarity in the data model as to their purpose and role
2. Queries that only need to reference the optional columns don't have to read from the main table
3. The need for additional indexes is reduced
4. Any relationships that exist only when the optional columns are present can make use of a FK constraint to the optional table<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Think of a warehouse - I wouldn't want to allow inventory levels to be changed unless a purchase order had details about when the goods were received (date, carrier, who signed for it, etc).  So any adjustments to inventory would refer to the primary key of the intake table, not the purchase order table itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking about is loosely related to the term [**database normalization**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/database-normalization-description#description-of-normalization). In short, database normalization is a way to reduce data redundancy with the goal of improving data reliability. Some people follow the same general methodology as normalization with their table design for other reasons such as improved performance, cleaner design, better maintainability (such as with schema changes).

I'm of a similar mindset as you. I prefer to group related data points together, and if I have enough of them that they're almost specific to their own type of object then I'll *usually* design my database to model them as a separate entity. Following this design pattern also helps prevent you from making a monolithic table. And views are useful for *denormalizing* the tables that store your data, into a central entity that can be consumed for a specific use case.